# Cannot pass file paths as command line argument where path contains space?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, command-prompt

I have a C# GUI allowing a user to select a file and then run this against objdump, outputting the content to the GUI.

However, I am having problems when the user selects a file where the path contains spaces, it causes the command line execution to break.

I had a look around Stackoverflow and there seem to be all these hacks for Windows scripting because paths with spaces aren't easy to solve. However, as I am passing the file name programatically I cannot do this/is there an easier way?

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK){
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;           //May contain spaces
        try
            {
                var proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "dumpbin.exe",
                        Arguments = "/DISASM " + filename,    // Causing this to fail
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    }
                };

                proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the filename with double quotes, just like you normally would from command line.

Try this:

```
Arguments = "/DISASM \"" + filename + "\"",
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put quotes around the path

```
pSInfo.Argument = @"""c:\test cases\testfile.csv""";
```

or if you prefer

```
pSInfo.Argument = "\"c:\\test cases\\testfile.csv\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around the `filename`:

```
Arguments = $"/DISASM \"{filename}\"",
```